# ImageList vs resources: How to organise images in Winforms?

Tags: .net, winforms

**TLDR:**

What is the best model to organise images in a project? Is it common and advised to create an `ImageList` at startup and access each image via its index or are resoruces the way to go? In any case please explain why.

**Detailed Problem:**

I am currently working on a piece of software which has been under development for quite a while now. It has partially been written in Visual Basic and it heavily relies on the `ImageList` class to organise all images in every part of the software. At the start of the application an `ImageList` gets created via a huge array containing all names of all image files which will ever bee accessible. Whenever you'd need an image, you'd need access to this object and get your image via the index of the image in the list.

I understand that this might have partially been useful in the past, as the resources in visual studio were not as handy to use and some controls only worked with these lists, for example the [`ToolBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbar(v=vs.110).aspx) (replaced by the [`ToolStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip(v=vs.110).aspx)) class which has a Poperty `ImageList`and each button just gets the index of its image in the `ImageList`.

I feel like this massive `ImageList` should be abandoned and there should be a slow migration towards organising those images in the resources, but I am not mainly a .net developer and don't know that much about winforms and its best practice.

Like asked in the TLDR: What is the best model to organise images in a project? Is it common and advised to create an `ImageList` at startup and access each image via its index or are resoruces the way to go? In any case please explain why.

Comment: Opinion questions are off-topic.  Winforms, while still supported, isn't in development anymore. It is what it is.

Comment: ImageList should only be used to provide images for ListView and TreeView, its deep copy behavior makes it too inefficient to manage large collections of images.  You ought to use a `List<Image>`.  Don't forget to Dispose() them when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a wpf project

I have two ideas in mind

1) Add a stackpanel in your window's xaml and your xaml code

for example

```
StackPanel ImagesStackPanel = new StackPanel();

foreach(Image img in Images) //your images enumerable
{

//here you can add also  other elements
 Image _img = (Image)XamlReader.Parse(@"<Image Name="{{here goes the image id}}" Height="400" Width="400" /> ");

   ImagesStackPanel.Children.Add(_img );
}


_Window.Content = ImagesStackPanel;
```

2)
If you are not worried about the cpu/ram usage 
and you care a lot about styling etc you can do the following

The other idea is to use the webbrowser or the cefsharp browser.
Create an html file with  html code  for media gallery, set your files as resources and just call their resource urls from the html code.

You can load your html code in stringbuilder and make any change you want in c# by replacing specific values that you can set as {{my value}} for example

```
//the html code -->   id='{{my  id}}' src='{{img url }}'

 //the c# code -->       _yourStringBuilder.ToString().Replace("{{my  id}}",id of the image).Replace("{{img url }}",url of the image)



 //** You can add any animation and css style you want**
```